# Which Filter parameters are supported by PublishTransactionsFilter

Tags: tom.net

The TOM .NET API has a handy `PublishTransactionsFilter` which accepts a `Filter` object as a parameter.

```
public PublishTransactionsFilter(
    Filter filter,
    Session session
)
```

Which parameters are supported for the Filter's `AdditionalCollumns` and `Conditions`?

The PublishTransactionsFilter documentation does not reveal it, the Filter documentation only mentions that the method which takes the Filter as a parameter defines which parameters it supports.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can use `Filter` and `PublishTransactionsFilter` as mentioned below:

```
Filter filter = new Filter();
filter.Conditions["ItemType"] = ItemType.Component;

PublishTransactionsFilter publishTransactionsFilter = PublishTransactionsFilter(filter, session);
publishTransactionsFilter.StartDate = startDate; 
publishTransactionsFilter.EndDate = endDate; 

XmlElement transactionList = GetListPublishTransactions(publishTransactionsFilter);
```

Here for the `Filter`:

- `Conditions:` are used to set related to ItemType, DateTime, .. soon
- `AdditionalColumns:` These are the names of optional columns (XML attributes) to include in the list. Which additional columns are supported depends on the list method for which the Filter is used.

Actually speaking, I haven't used `AdditionalColumns` yet.

### Update:

`Conditions` are similar to RowFilter, so it should support

- `ItemType` - filters certain types of items
- `SchemaPurpose` - filters certain types of Schemas
- `BasedOnSchema` - filters one or more specific Schemas
- `LockFilter` - filters items with a certain type of lock on them
- `LockResult` - filters items with a certain type of lock on them
- `LockUser` - filters items locked by a specific user
- `Recursive` - retrieves items recursively, that is, also from sub-organizational items

### Example:

```
filter.Conditions["BasedOnSchema"] = mComponent.Schema;
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this in the API documentation indeed. My question is more specific "Wich parameters are supported for the Filter's AdditionalCollumns and Conditions?". Actually I think "ItemType" cannot be used as a parameter with PublishTransactionsFilter, it is ignored by the method. I would like to know the full list of supported parameters.

Comment: @JanH: Conditions are similar to RowFilter

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the following values for `AdditionalColumns`:

```
"allow"
"deny"
"managed"
"versions"
"url"
"xmlname"
"checkoutuser"
"path"
```